# Wix installer - copy attribute value to another attribute

Tags: wix, wix3, wix3.8

What I want to do is copy the value of a single property, and place it as the value of another property. Is this possible with Wix?

```
<Property Id="PROP1" Value="default"  Secure="yes"/>
```

I want `PROP2` to have the same value some where during the UI sequence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Custom action to accomplish it. Define action as

`<CustomAction Id="SetMyProperty" Execute="immediate" Property="PROP2" Value="[PROP1]" />`

Then call it in `<InstallUISequence>` or `<InstallExecuteSequence>` when you need it set, something like

`<Custom Action="SetMyProperty" After="FileCost"></Custom>`

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. Is this also possible on a button click instead of the UI sequence?

Comment: It is easier to do this on button click just add it as publish event `<UI>
      <Publish Dialog="DialogName" Control="ButtonName" Property="PROP2" Value="[PROP1]"></Publish>     
    </UI>`

Comment: Great, this is what I needed.

Answer (score 2):

Although @Mischo5500 answer is correct, there is a more elegant way to achieve the same. You can use a special element, [`<SetProperty>`](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/wix/setproperty.html), which was designed exactly for that purpose.

The benefits of using it is:

- It's just one line of WiX code
- It is scheduled properly by default into both sequences
- The name of the element is more natural and self-explanatory

Thus, the above example can be transformed into the following:

```
<SetProperty Id="PROP2" Value="[PROP1]" After="FileCost" />
```

Comment: Thanks, but can this be used on button clicks, like Mischo5500's answer?

Comment: Nope, that's a whole different story. Use the way outlined in @Mischo5500's comment.